# Could not resolve in GAL

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption to work with outlook 2003. I want to access folder on sharedMailBox and code is failing:

```
        RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
        session.LogonExchangeMailbox(Constants.UserName,Constants.ExchangeServerName);
        RDOStore store = session.Stores.GetSharedMailbox(Constants.MailBoxName);
        RDOFolder folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

When i am trying to get RDOStore object, i get "Could not resolve in GAL: Mailbox - MTS SH Support".

I was using this code before:

```
        RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
        session.Logon();
        RDOFolder InboxFolder = rSession.GetFolderFromPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Constants.MailBoxName, Constants.InboxFolder));
```

And it was working, but after several hours of work it fails when trying to create RDOFolder with error "Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER".

So what is the correct way to access sharedMailbox folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ou.. problem resolved. Everything was in .GetSharedMailBox parametr. I thought that it was SharedMailBox Name(Mailbox - Example mailbox). In reality it was mailbox`s address. Maybe it will be usefull for somebody!